# Cambiar propiedades ReadOnly

Tags: visual-studio, vb

Tengan en cuenta que soy nuevo en Visual Studio y en Visual Basic

En resumen, estoy haciendo una prueba para cambiar la fuente de un texto.

```
        If respuesta = vbYes Then
            Button1.Font.Bold = True
            Button1.Font.Italic = True
            Button1.Font.Size = 12
        End If
```

Ahora, lo que pasa es que me sale un error en las propiedades .Bold, .Italic y .Size. Dice
BC30526: La propiedad 'Bold' es 'ReadOnly'. Si alguien me puede explicar como poder cambiar el valor de propiedades ReadOnly lo apreciaría. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando vb.Net, `Font` es un objeto del Namespace: `System.Drawing` y sus propiedades son todas `ReadOnly` y por tanto no se le puede cambiar su valor, lo que habrá que hacer es crear una nueva instancia del objeto Font y asignarla a propiedad `Button1.Font`, de la siguiente forma.

```
    If respuesta = vbYes Then
        Button1.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12.0f, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
    End If
```

En el [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) puedes encontrar información sobre como usar el objeto `Font`